# How to use crypt method for string in ruby?please explain with example

Tags: ruby, string

I am not able to understand that function. I have read the below content with no example so not able to understand
`crypt(salt_str) → new_str` click to toggle source
Applies a one-way cryptographic hash to `str` by invoking the standard library function crypt(3) with the given salt string.

While the format and the result are system and implementation dependent, using a salt matching the regular expression `\A[a-zA-Z0-9./]{2}` should be valid and safe on any platform, in which only the first two characters are significant.

This method is for use in system specific scripts, so if you want a cross-platform hash function consider using Digest or OpenSSL instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`String#crypt`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-crypt) is an instance method on a string expecting another string as an argument:

```
"Foo Bar".crypt("Baz")
#=> "BazLv1TTSVteU"
```